# Convert UTC Seconds to String in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column with UTC Seconds in SQL.

How can I convert UTCSeconds to varchar in order to get this output in a `select` statement:

```
DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss
```

Example: `1400249277` in table

`16-May-2014 15:07:57` as output of Select statement

Comment: What made you think it is UTC date time?

Comment: @M.Ali because the column name is UTCStartTime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a SQLServer available right now but this looks like it might be what you're looking for : [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms186819.aspx). You are probably considering the number of seconds since January the 1st 1970, so it would be something alike :

`SELECT DATEADD (second, <your number of seconds>, '1970-01-01')`